# Rename - what does "s//" vs "y//" mean?

Tags: rename, perl

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) gives two examples:

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

So it's either s or y and then `/replaceThis/withThis`

What does the leading s and y mean? Are there other options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first case:

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

you are running a regular expression against filenames and replacing the matching part of expressions (.bak at the end of a file name) with the second expression (which is empty).

In the second case:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

you are matching against the regular expression pattern space and transliterating to the target. In other words, the range A-Z is changed to the range a-z, making the filenames lower case.

I suggest you look at the man page for [sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sed.1.html) for more commands and more details. I believe the 's' command is used most often. As well, [regex (section 7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/regex.7.html) and perl documentation may also be of help. In particular, [here's a tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) on perl and regular expressions.

---

From `man sed`:

```
s/regexp/replacement/    
       Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If  success‐
       ful,   replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.   The
       replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
       portion  of  the  pattern  space  which matched, and the special
       escapes \1 through \9 to refer  to  the  corresponding  matching
       sub-expressions in the regexp.

y/source/dest/  
       Transliterate  the  characters in the pattern space which appear
       in source to the corresponding character in dest.
```

Comment: Thanks much - I'm just not sure pointing people to 'sed' is the best idea given its multitude of implementations, especially between any given linux distro and OSX

Comment: @aaaaaa This site is exclusively about Ubuntu.